# I cannot start parrot os on my virtual machine

Tags: shell, parrot-os

When starting, the following appears:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxqae.png)

I already looked in the parrot documentation and can't find anything :(

Comment: Find out where the OS/bootload is installed. You need to switch to that device or partition. For example, in the shell type `fs0:` And then load the bootloader Ex. `\efi\xxxx\grubx64.efi`.  Search "how to boot from EFI shell" for more information

Comment: ideally startup.nsh should have this information. You can try `edit startup.nsh` to see something is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, I will see that if I can solve it, if not, I will try another operating system

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem this is how you fix it

allow it to go to the Shell

First 
[image: First type fs0: in the shell click enter]

Next you will Create a start up file

[image: Type - edit startup.nsh and click enter]

[image]

You need to Save the file

Press CTRL+S to save .

Next

Press ENTER to confirm

Next

Press CTRL+Q to exit

---

Last you need to reboot

[image: reboot]

Now this command will run every time you start up the virtual machine